# onClick button not working in a basic android project

Tags: java, android, xml

I have just started programming in Android and I couldn't get the result on clicking button that I expected. Here s the code.

**.java file**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidLove extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_love);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_love, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

}
```

**.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AndroidLove" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/Button"
    android:onClick="onButtonClicked" />
```

**strings.xml file**

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">AndroidLove</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line</string>
<string name="Button">Get Lyrics</string>
```

On clicking the button, the following text should be displayed but its not displayed:-

```
First Line

Second Line

Third Line
```

Please help

Comment: what is Target level of your API ? `android:onClick` is for API level +4, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Maybe and probably your binding is wrong about onclick, try below code instead of top. Put that code into your `onCreate` method.

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

Comment: givin -1 for a right answer is not good too. It´s better to just advise the answering person to explain it and wait if he/she it is doing before givin -1.

Comment: he adds the text directly via the `android:text=...`, how is this supposed to fix the underlying issue?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs if you say your comment to me I don't down vote to this question, i just say to fix that

Comment: guys, he just setting button's text with android:text="@string/Button"
but he wants to set textview text as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: `android:text="@string/hello_world"` in `TextView` is already there just need to set it visible.

Comment: this answer is wrong, OP just wants to change visibility not setText to TextView

Comment: then probably the binding is wrong for button click

Comment: @shayan --- no, this wasn´t mentioned to You...just to the person who have done it :). But the answer is wright, because OP surely wants to make text visible, but he has forget to ad the text :)

Comment: i just edited my answer, let the @user3767175 try it.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs OP set text in xml file, why he need do that again on code?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Read my comment on answer, I think problem of OP is Target API, not setting value on code

Comment: Why do you think like that @shayan pourvatan

Comment: because the OP code is right and this should be worked, so only guess is Target API LEvel

Comment: i think the @user3767175 should give details about his problem.. that way the asking question is not right

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the string value from the strings.xml file which can be acheived by

```
String st =getResources.getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

Then set that to textview by

```
textView.setText(st);
```

Comment: absolutely not, `android:text="@string/hello_world"` should work on its own

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
 public class AndroidLove extends Activity {
   private Button button1; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_love);
      textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      button1  = (Button)findViewByid(R.id.button1);
      button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        // do your stuff here
           String _data =getResources.getString(R.string.hello_world);
           textView.setText(_data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  });
}
```